# Merge two arrays in third array also sort the third array in ascending order

Tags: java, arrays

I want to write java program to merge two arrays in third array. Also sort the third array in ascending order. But duplication of digit is not allowed..how can i write this program. This is what i have done so far..

```
public class combine {
  public static void main(String[]args){

  int[]a = {1, 2, 3};
  int[]b = {4, 5, 6};
//  int[]c = new int[10];
  int[]c = new int[a.length+b.length];
  int i;
  for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
     c[i] = a[i];

     for(int j=0; j<b.length; j++)
        c[i++]=b[j];

  for(int k=0; k<c.length; k++)
  System.out.print(c[k]+" ");
}

}
```

Comment: you could use java language

Comment: what you have tried so far..??

Comment: Duplication of digits or numbers?

Comment: You should also be using braces to keep your nested loops in check.

Answer (score 2):

First create the arrays:

```
Integer[] a = new Integer[]{8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0};
Integer[] b = new Integer[]{0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21};
```

Convert the arrays to lists for simpler handling:

```
List<Integer> aList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(a));
List<Integer> bList = Arrays.asList(b);
```

Merge the lists:

```
aList.addAll(bList);
```

Sort the list in ascending order:

```
aList.sort(new Comparator<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer integer, Integer t1) {
        return integer.compareTo(t1);
    }
});
```

Convert the list to a set (sets do not have duplicate values per definition):

```
Set<Integer> uniqueList = new HashSet<>(aList);
```

Print the merged, sorted array without duplicate values:

```
System.out.println(uniqueList);
```

Reuslt:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 13, 21]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this following code,adding the values in both arrays to set to remove duplicates and using the tree set can get you the order and later populate any ds as you desire

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    Set<Integer> mySet = new TreeSet<Integer>();
    int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    int[] b = { 3, 5, 4, 6 };
    for (int i : a) {
        mySet.add(i);
    }
    for (int i : b) {
        mySet.add(i);
    }
    System.out.println(mySet);
}
```

**Output :**  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

Comment: Nice solution! I did not know TreeSets yet. Shorter way of adding is to use Integer arrays (instead of int) and use  `mySet.addAll(Arrays.asList(a));` or `Collections.addAll(mySet, a);` instad of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could add all of the numbers (or digits) in both of the arrays to a TreeSet, then just keep calling `mySet.first()` and adding it to the result array, then `mySet.remove(mySet.first())` until the set is empty. Because it is a TreeSet, repeatedly getting and removing the first (aka lowest) element in the set will yield an ascending order.

Another thing you could do is sort both arrays, then use a round of merge sort to combine the arrays, with a check where if the previously inserted number is equal to the number to be inserted, don't do anything and skip the number.

Answer (score 0):

You could merge a and b in a temp array, then use Arrays.sort(temp);  and do a linear search in temp to copy only unique entries in c

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `TreeSet` which is both sorted and without duplicated values. Here is an example of that:

```
Integer[] numbers1 = { 7, 7, 8, 9, 10, 8, 8, 9, 6, 5, 4 };
Integer[] numbers2 = { 12, 7, 4, 6, 10, 8, 2, 9, 5, 5, 3 };

List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(numbers1);
List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(numbers2);

Set<Integer> set = new TreeSet<Integer>(list1);
set.addAll(new TreeSet<Integer>(list2));

System.out.println(set.toString());
```

Here is the working [ideone](http://ideone.com/knYoE4).

Result: `[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12]`

NOTE: If you can't use `Integer[]` but only `int[]` you'll have to convert those first. There are multiple questions already for this here on StackOverflow.